# regex pattern issue with special characters and spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract only the letters using the split method and I'm not getting the expected results. Here's my code

```
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter greeting: ");
    String greeting = myInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String[] myGreeting = greeting.split("(.[^a-z])*");
    for(String stry: myGreeting){
        System.out.println(stry);
    }
```

My output looks like:

```
Enter greeting: 
Hello!! my Man
h
e
l
l

m

m
a
n
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: for this example: hellomyman. But displayed as above through a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect, it seems you want the following instead ...

```
String[] myGreeting = greeting.split("[^a-z]+");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/d3qJhD)